# Databinding compile error after upgrading from Android Studio '3.2 Canary 16' to '3.2 Beta 1'

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding

I just upgraded Android Studio from 3.2 Canary 16' to '3.2 Beta 1'. Now my project no longer compiles. I'm using Kotlin + Databinding which I think is the issue.
This is the build stacktrace:

```
e: [kapt] An exception occurred: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to parse data binding compiler options. Params:
    null : null
    kapt.kotlin.generated : /home/thomas/Android/Projects/MyProject/app/build/generated/source/kaptKotlin/debug
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.readArguments(ProcessDataBinding.java:184)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.doProcess(ProcessDataBinding.java:83)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.process(ProcessDataBinding.java:73)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorWrapper.process(annotationProcessing.kt:99)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:705)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1068)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:55)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.runAnnotationProcessing(Kapt3Extension.kt:216)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:164)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:108)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:85)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:370)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:61)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:361)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:126)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:154)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:95)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:50)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:405)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:927)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:957)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:926)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:404)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor164.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
    at android.databinding.tool.CompilerArguments$Companion.readFromOptions(CompilerArguments.kt:172)
    at android.databinding.tool.CompilerArguments.readFromOptions(CompilerArguments.kt)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.readArguments(ProcessDataBinding.java:177)
    ... 52 more

> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED
```

- Gradle plugin version: `3.2.0-beta01`
- Kotlin version: `1.2.50` (jdk8)

I also tried adding `kapt "androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:3.2.0-beta01"` to the app gradle but it did not make any difference.

**Edit:**

- Downgrading to Kotlin `1.2.41` did not solve the issue.
- After some more testing it looks like this bug appeared in Gradle plugin version `3.2.0-alpha17`. (alpha16 works fine)

Comment: I suggest filing an issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192721&template=1096850

Comment: @yogurtearl Thanks for your reply. I just found the issue and don't think I need to add this to the issue tracker as it was my fault. I forgot to add a dependency to the project level build gradle. Somehow it always worked before without the dependency but now it looks like it is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue after some testing in another project. I did not have the following line in the project level dependencies:

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
```

This never was an issue before but it looks like this is required in the newer Android Studio versions if you use Kotlin and Databinding.

Comment: This causes an error: **:shared:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED**